# Run Function if Order Meta Exists - WooCommerce

Tags: custom-field, plugins

If a checkbox is checked, it saves a value of 1 for a 'my_checkbox' custom order field in WooCommerce. I'm editing the order admin table and I need to be able to echo a particular icon url if the value of 'my_checkbox' equals 1. I just don't know how to check if the value is equal to one so I can echo the url. Any ideas?

To make troubleshooting easier, here's the code:

```
/**
* Add checkbox field to the checkout
**/
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'match_previous_order_checkbox');

function match_previous_order_checkbox( $checkout ) {
echo '<div id="match_the_order">';
woocommerce_form_field( 'my_checkbox', array(
     'type'     => 'checkbox',
     'class'    => array('form-row notes'),
     'label'    => __( 'This is a previous order' , 'woothemes'),
     'required' => false,
    ), 
    $checkout->get_value( 'my_checkbox' ));
    echo '</div>';
}
/**
* Update the order meta with field value
**/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'match_order_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function match_order_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_checkbox']) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My_Checkbox', esc_attr($_POST['my_checkbox']));
    }
}
global $order;
$match_order_meta = get_post_meta( $order_id , 'My_Checkbox' );
```

`$match_order_meta = get_post_meta( $order->ID , 'My_Checkbox' );` doesn't work either. Also whether or not I include `global $order;` doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce orders are posts and behave the same as any WordPress post. So you can use the same WordPress functions to update or read the post meta data.

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

For your example I'd suggest:

```
$match_order_meta = get_post_meta( $order->ID, 'My_Checkbox', TRUE);
```

The 'TRUE' flag tells WordPress to return the value as a string. Without the TRUE flag you'll get an array. Again take a look at the docs below.

You might also:

```
echo '<!-- $order->ID -->';
```

To make sure you have the correct ID.

Here are the docs [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I'm using: `<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta( $order->ID , 'my_checkbox' ); ?>` but no values are returned, even though orders exist.

Comment: Does your `$order-ID` equal the post ID?

Comment: I put my code in the question above. The $order id should be the post id. Here's the code from WooCommerce: `global $post, $woocommerce;
 $order = new WC_Order( $post->ID );`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up getting it by just using $post->ID and left $order->ID completely out of it.